# Парсер/демон на php падает без причины

Tags: php, парсер, демон

Всем привет. Пишу скрипт загрузки товаров в интернет магазин из xml прайса. Столкнулся с той проблемой что на моем сервере парсер отрабатывает нормально, однако на хостинге клиента прекращает работу спустя 20-60  минут после запуска. В итоге я решил проверить как долго вообще будет выполнятся php скрипт на клиентском хостинге, для проверки написал что то вроде демона:

```
        <?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set("memory_limit", "128M");
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

    function shutdown()
    {
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/log/shutdown_log.txt', 'Выполнили функцию shutdown!'.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        $err_arr = error_get_last();
        $err = 'type - '.$err_arr['type'] . ' | message - '. $err_arr['message'] . ' | file - '.$err_arr['file']. ' | line - '.$err_arr['line'];
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/log/shutdown_log.txt', $err, FILE_APPEND);

    }

    function sig_handler($signo)
    {
        $info = "\n" . 'received signal ' . $signo . "\n";
        $info .= "\n" . 'Выполнили функцию sig_handler! ' . $signo . "\n";
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/log/sig_handler_log.txt', $info.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        $err_arr = error_get_last();
        $err = 'type - '.$err_arr['type'] . ' | message - '. $err_arr['message'] . ' | file - '.$err_arr['file']. ' | line - '.$err_arr['line'];
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/log/sig_handler_log.txt', $err, FILE_APPEND);
        exit;
    }

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
declare(ticks = 1);
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "sig_handler");
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "sig_handler");


$time = date('H-i-s');
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/log/time_test_ON.txt', $time);

while(true){
    $time = date('H-i-s');
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/log/time_test_log.txt', $time);
    sleep(1);
}
```

После запуска демона через консоль, он прекращает работу примерно через 20 минут, при этом shutdown() и sig_handler() - никаких логов не создают. Хотя если убить скрипт через консоль командой kill pid то обе функции отрабатывают нормально, то есть логи создаются.

В общем я в тупике, предполагаю что это некое ограничение на хостинге, однако не могу понять в чем именно оно состоит и как его пофиксить.

Comment: рекомендую вам обернуть работу скрипта в `try catch`. Кто знает что всплывёт. Так же нужно чтобы скрипт работал без предупреждений.

Comment: Ну в выше приведенном примере использован простейший цикл так что там try catch думаю никчему. А вот в парсере у меня да много где try catch используется. Для загрузки товаров на wordpress применяю библиотеку woocommerce api, так вот там совсем без предупреждений почему то не получается. Одни и те же товары раз загружаются нормально, а в следующий раз библиотека генерит ошибки вида:
Элемент с указанным именем и ярлыком уже существует в этой таксономии. [term_exists]
Хотя я вроде бы и проверки по базе делаю что нет такого ярлыка, но все равно не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Получил ответ от хостинга:
"Здравствуйте, на наших серверах виртуального хостинга есть ограничение в 1200 секунд на время работы пользовательского процесса. Запущенные Вами процессы были остановлены при превышении данного лимита:" - так что таки да на их стороне была проблема.